# OpenRowset filter query results by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to filter some querys by date. i am using OPENROWSET to extract data from DBF tables but i can not filter by date, Visual Studio says that the data type is Database Date [DT_DBDATE]. I am using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(
'VFPOLEDB', 
'C:\FOLDER\VFPDB\TABLES' 
;'';'', 
'SELECT *
FROM pedidoc
WHERE date BETWEEN '20120301' and '20120330''
) AS pedidoc
```

but sql server says 'incorrect syntax neat '20120301'
any idea how to filter inside OPENROWSET?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use double-quotes for your filter and use the date format with `-` between the date parts.

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(
'VFPOLEDB', 
'C:\FOLDER\VFPDB\TABLES' 
;'';'', 
'SELECT *
FROM pedidoc
WHERE date BETWEEN ''2012-03-01'' and ''2012-03-30'' '
) AS pedidoc
```

Comment: show another error
    OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB" for linked server "(null)" returned message 
    "Operator/operand type mismatch.".
    Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
    Cannot execute the query "SELECT *
    FROM pedidoc

Comment: Is the column defined as a date data type in the source?

Comment: Yes it is Field type = Date

Answer (score 0):

Inside OPENROWSET, SELECT statement must be of syntax acceptable by OLEDB provider. In this case, use not SQL SERVER syntax, but VISUAL FOXPRO syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(
'VFPOLEDB', 
'C:\FOLDER\VFPDB\TABLES' 
;'';'',
'SELECT * FROM pedidoc WHERE BETWEEN(date, {^2012-03-01}, {^2012-03-30})'
) AS pedidoc
```

There might be problem with date/time type conversion from VFP->MSSQL therefore convert them to string using DTOS function (date to string):

```
'SELECT DTOS(date) as datestr FROM pedidoc WHERE BETWEEN(date, {^2012-03-01}, {^2012-03-30})'
```